# Is it Possible to Return Two ArrayList values in One method in java?

Tags: java, collections, return

Is there any way to return two values from one method....

Example:

```
public Class Sample
{
  public List<Date> returnTwoArrayList()
   {
      List<Date> startDate=new ArrayList<Date>();
      
      List<Date> endDate=new ArrayList<Date>();

     //So I want to Return Two values startDate and endDate ...It is Possible????
   }
}
```

i'm calling this method into My Service class and in that Storing `StartDate` and `endDate` into Database here these are Two different Columns

```
**StartDate      endDate**
2012-12-01     2012-12-05
2012-12-01     2012-12-15
2012-12-02     2012-12-10
2012-12-20     2012-12-25
2012-12-25     2012-12-31
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You **cannot** return separate structures via one method call, but you can return a **composite** of them. For example, returning a list of your lists would be a possible solution:

```
   public List<List<Date>> returnTwoArrayList()
   {
      List<Date> startDates = new ArrayList<Date>();
      List<Date> endDates = new ArrayList<Date>();

      List<List<Date>> result = new ArrayList<List<Date>>();
      result.add(startDates);
      result.add(endDates);

      return result;
   }
```

You can use `get()` method to retrieve these lists later on.
Suppose you have made a call like `List<List<Date>> twoLists = returnTwoArrayList();` then
you can get `startDate` by calling `twoLists.get(0)`  and similarly `endDate` with `twoLists.get(1)`

Comment: ok... then i want to separate StartDate and endDate in another Service Class in that time how to Do?

Comment: @NarasimhamK see my answer, i added explanation for that.

Answer (score 6):

No you can not return two value from a method.

Best way would be create a custom class with two field and return that object.

```
class ObjectHolder{
    private List<Date> startDate=new ArrayList<Date>();
    private List<Date> endDate=new ArrayList<Date>();

    <getter & setter method>
}
```

and -

```
public ObjectHolder returnTwoArrayList(){
    ObjectHolder oh = new ObjectHolder();
    List<Date> startDate=new ArrayList<Date>();
    oh.setStartDate(startDate);
    List<Date> endDate=new ArrayList<Date>();
    oh.setEndDate(endDate);
    return oh;
}
```

Comment: Correct.. it is possible to create Bean class But is Their any other alternate way,i mean with in the class only ....Thanks for your replay..

Comment: The class can be a nested one and be within the same class.

Answer (score 2):

You can

- provide one or both lists as argument(s) to populate.
- have two lists which are fields of the instance of the method and access these via getters.
- return an array of two lists or a list of lists.
- return a custom type which wrap the two lists.  I wouldn't use getters, just makes the fields public.
- have a single list of intervals

I believe the last is the best solution.

```
public class Sample {
  public List<Interval> returnListOfStartToEndDates() {
      List<Interval> intervals=new ArrayList<>();

      return intervals;
   }
}
```

Joda-time has an [Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class which is more efficient than creating two Date objects, but you can also create your own.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom class like this

```
TimeSpan(ArrayList<Date> startDate, ArrayList<Date> endDate)
```

and return that Object.

Answer (score 1):

Directly, no, unless you count returning an array of two `List`s, or a `List` of `List`s with the stated understanding to the caller that it would contain exactly two entries and what value each one would represent.

Other than that, you could always write a `Pair` class and use that, which would be better because it removes the dependence on that assumption about the dimension of the return value, and you will find that a `Pair` type comes in handy in many, many situations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can use Map like the following,

```
public Map<String, List<Date>> getBothDates() {
  List<Date> startDate = new ArrayList<Date>();
  List<Date> endDate = new ArrayList<Date>();
  Map<String, List<Date>> bothDates = new HashMap<String, List<Date>>();
  bothDates.put("startDate", startDate);
  bothDates.put("endDate", endDate);    
  return bothDates;
}
```

To fetch both dates simple iterate the map,

```
public void printBothDates() {
   Map<String, List<Date>> bothDates = getBothDates();
   for(Entry<String, List<Date>> entry : bothDates.entrySet()) {
     if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("startDate", entry.getKey())) {
       for(Date d : entry.getValue()) {
          System.out.println("startDate---"+d);
       }
     } else if(StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase("endDate", entry.getKey())) {
       for(Date d : entry.getValue()) {
          System.out.println("endDate---"+d);
       }
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyClass {
    public ArrayList<ArrayList> TwoArrayList() {

        ArrayList cars = new ArrayList();
        cars.add("Volvo");
        cars.add("BMW");
        cars.add("Ford");
        cars.add("Mazda");

        ArrayList fruits = new ArrayList();
        fruits.add("Apple");
        fruits.add("Mango");
        fruits.add("Banana");
        fruits.add("Orange");

        ArrayList <ArrayList> twoArrayList = new ArrayList <ArrayList>();
        twoArrayList.add(cars);
        twoArrayList.add(fruits);

        return twoArrayList;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       MyClass obj = new MyClass();

        ArrayList <ArrayList> Arlist= obj.TwoArrayList();
        
        System.out.println(Arlist.get(0));/**FIRST ARRAY LIST*/
        
        System.out.println(Arlist.get(0).get(0));/**FIRST ARRAY LIST FIRST Element*/

        System.out.println(Arlist.get(1));/**SECOND ARRAY LIST*/
        
        System.out.println(Arlist.get(1).get(0));/**SECOND ARRAY LIST FIRST Element*/
    }  
}
```

***OUTPUT IS HERE***

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wilWy.png)